# Gradle: change property of task from a plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins, configuration

This is about as basic as it could be... but I haven't found the answer either here or at gradle.org or generally.  NB Gradle 4.4.1, Groovy 2.4 (used by Eclipse-Gradle) or 2.6 (command line).  Java 8.

In my build.gradle I have the `application` plugin and have set the main class:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "core.ConsoleHandler"
```

... including this plugin adds 2 "dependency tasks" (if that's the right term: i.e. `build` is now "dependent" on them): `taskZip` and `taskTar`.

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) we see that `taskZip` is of type `Zip`... and looking up the doc for this subclass of `Task` [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) we see that one of the properties of such a `Task` is `destinationDir`... i.e. where the .zip file ends up.

All I want to do is set this to a specific directory.

I've tried (in build.gradle) things like

```
task application.taskZip { 
    destinationDir = 'D:/bobble'
}
```

and

```
taskZip { 
    destinationDir = 'D:/bobble'
}
```

and

```
destinationDir = 'D:/bobble'
```

These all produce fatal errors.  What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `distZip` not `taskZip`

```
apply plugin: 'application'
distZip { 
    destinationDir = file('D:/bobble') 
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot... no wonder I was having problems! I'm wondering whether to delete the question... but for me you deserve the points!  I'm thinking of not deleting not least because even if I had put "distZip" I still wouldn't have known about `file( ... )`.

Comment: (although the error message from putting a String gives you a clue of course...)

Answer (score 0):

`destinationDir` takes a `File` parameter

Try something like that :

```
tasks.withType(taskZip) {
    destinationDir = file("D:/bobble")
}
```

Comment: You do not need to construct `File` objects on your own in Gradle, use the `file(...)` method instead.